# Sein + Dative, Genitive or Nominative

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

In the Spiegel's [article](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-verschieden-unterschiedlich-a-327300.html) I cathed my eye the following sentence:

> Henry und ich waren verschiedener Meinung.

As far as I can see, the adjektiv `verschieden` is in `Dative` case (`-er` + Female noun). Is it correct or it's in `Genitive`? Actually, I expected to see here `Nominative`, rather than `Dative` or `Genitive`.

Can I assume, that after `sein` should always go the `Dative` or the sentence above is just an idiom?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use nominative in this example - Henry and I are not *opinions*

> Henry und ich sind Lehrer.

Would be using nominative, just as in English.

Just as well, *verschiedener Meinung* is **not** dative in your example case.

Let's consider another example to make it clearer

> Der Katholik und der Buddhist sind unterschiedlichen Glaubens

We're using a masculine substantive to be able to detect the case properly - *Glaubens* is clearly genitive.

This construct is called *genitivus qualitatis* or, in German, *Genitiv der Beschaffenheit* and is used to describe a qualitative attribute of an object. Other examples of this usage are

> Ich bin protestantischen Glaubens
>
> die Freude war kurzer Dauer
>
> der Mann war mittleren Alters
>
> Ihre Familie war chinesischen Ursprungs

Modern German tends to use this specific case less and less and replaces it with prepositional expressions like

> der Mann war von mittlerem Alter
>
> die Freude war von kurzer Dauer

(Here, *von* asks for the dative)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed expalanation. Just to be sure I got it correctly, according to *Genitiv der Beschaffenheit*, can I say: *«Ich war gutes Students»*?

Comment: No, you can't. That would be a predicative - *Ich war ein guter Student*. Stressing it a bit far, you could just barely say: *Ich war ein Student großen Fleißes*